# Checking if an user input is in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a small java program that asks the user for an input and checks if the input is in the array and redirects the user to a HTML page if the input is in the array.

```
package ticketnummercheck;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketnummerCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ticketnummer = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ticketnummer:");
        ticketnummer = input.nextInt();

        String [] ticketnummerDB = {"1234", "12345", "123456", "123456"};


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
if(Arrays.asList(ticketnummerDB)
         .contains(String.valueOf(ticketnummer))) {
    // contains value
}
else {
    // does not contain value
}
```